# Maven: Build different WAR files of same project including different module dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a maven project consisting of a parent project and several modules, `foo`, `bar`, `foobar` and `web`.

```
<modules>
    <module>foo</module>
    <module>bar</module>
    <module>foobar</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>
```

`web` has `foo`, `bar` and `foobar` as dependencies and is built as WAR. For several reasons I need to build another WAR that contains `foo` and `bar` but not `foobar`. What is the best way to achieve this? Is there any possibility to use maven profiles to define the different dependencies? Or is the best solution just to add a second war-building module (e.g. `web2`) without `foobar` as dependency like this answer suggests:
[Maven generating two different WAR files for same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057490/maven-generating-two-different-war-files-for-same-project/16057906#16057906) (see "Multi module structure" in that answer)

Comment: Make another module web-2 as web with different dependencies...cleanest solution...

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try a second web-module.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming artifact type of your top level pom is "Pom", the modules node is just an aggregator and specifies build execution order - it doesn't specify what the dependencies for each child module are.

You can just add web2 as another module at the bottom in the parent pom, and then in web2's pom you can specify artifact type of war and dependencies of foo and bar.  Foo and bar will be included in your war artifact, and foobar will not.

Comment: You should never rely on the order of build based on the order of the modules in pom file. Always define the correct dependencies between the modules and maven will handle that....